# How to dynamically adding new roles with permissions in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have custom user, role, userstore, rolestore. I can do authentication operations. But i want dynamic authorization. Adding new role and relation role and permissions and set this role to user.
I want something like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/S731K.jpg

Users model

```
namespace App.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("AppUsers")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(128)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(1024)]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(128)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Role models

```
namespace App.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("Role")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserStore

```
namespace App.Identity
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using App.Data;
    using App.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.Internal;

    public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question: do you need backend or frontend help? Also, what have you tried? From what you provided it looks like you need [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class methods, namely `AddToRoleAsync`, and `RemoveFromRoleAsync`.

Comment: I need backend help. For example i have Users CRUD pages. I create a new role 
and give this role just list the users permission and I create second role, this role have create, delete and list the users permission. I have to do them dynamically

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a new role, you need to discover all controllers and their actions and choose role can access which controllers and actions.

```
public class MvcControllerDiscovery : IMvcControllerDiscovery
{
    private List<MvcControllerInfo> _mvcControllers;
    private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

    public MvcControllerDiscovery(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MvcControllerInfo> GetControllers()
    {
        if (_mvcControllers != null)
            return _mvcControllers;

        _mvcControllers = new List<MvcControllerInfo>();

        var items = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
            .ActionDescriptors.Items
            .Where(descriptor => descriptor.GetType() == typeof(ControllerActionDescriptor))
            .Select(descriptor => (ControllerActionDescriptor)descriptor)
            .GroupBy(descriptor => descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var actionDescriptors in items)
        {
            if (!actionDescriptors.Any())
                continue;

            var actionDescriptor = actionDescriptors.First();
            var controllerTypeInfo = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;
            var currentController = new MvcControllerInfo
            {
                AreaName = controllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>()?.RouteValue,
                DisplayName = controllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName,
                Name = actionDescriptor.ControllerName,
            };

            var actions = new List<MvcActionInfo>();
            foreach (var descriptor in actionDescriptors.GroupBy(a => a.ActionName).Select(g => g.First()))
            {
                var methodInfo = descriptor.MethodInfo;
                actions.Add(new MvcActionInfo
                {
                    ControllerId = currentController.Id,
                    Name = descriptor.ActionName,
                    DisplayName = methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName,
                });
            }

            currentController.Actions = actions;
            _mvcControllers.Add(currentController);
        }

        return _mvcControllers;
    }
}
```

in `RoleController` and `Create` action return list of all controllers:

```
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMvcControllerDiscovery _mvcControllerDiscovery;

    public RoleController(IMvcControllerDiscovery mvcControllerDiscovery)
    {
        _mvcControllerDiscovery = mvcControllerDiscovery;
    }

    // GET: Role/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["Controllers"] = _mvcControllerDiscovery.GetControllers();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Create role page will be something like this:
[image: Create Dynamic Role]

For discovering razor pages read [Discovering controller actions and Razor Pages in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://joonasw.net/view/discovering-actions-and-razor-pages)

After creating role, assign roles to user and implement custom authorization filter to check weather user can access requested action and controller:

```
public class DynamicAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public DynamicAuthorizationFilter(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!IsProtectedAction(context))
            return;

        if (!IsUserAuthenticated(context))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        var actionId = GetActionId(context);
        var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        var roles = await (
            from user in _dbContext.Users
            join userRole in _dbContext.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
            join role in _dbContext.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
            where user.UserName == userName
            select role
        ).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var accessList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MvcControllerInfo>>(role.Access);
            if (accessList.SelectMany(c => c.Actions).Any(a => a.Id == actionId))
                return;
        }

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
```

I have implement dynamic role-based authorization in this way. for full detail take look at [Dynamic Role-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/mo-esmp/DynamicRoleBasedAuthorizationNETCore)
  github repo.

Comment: How to discover razor pages? I don't use controllers. My pages razor pages in asp.net core 2.2

Comment: Read this post for [Discovering controller actions and Razor Pages in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://joonasw.net/view/discovering-actions-and-razor-pages)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for me